# Spring Data @Query - How to get current date + day

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to get records that have `date_time` column is in a week from now, in a month from now

I have a query like this

```
public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<Booking, Long> {

@Query("SELECT b " +
"FROM BOOKING b " +
"WHERE b.date_time < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY and b.date_time > NOW()")
List<Booking> getListBooking();

}
```

In MySQL, `NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY` is working but in JPA `@Query`, I don't know which function is correspond to it.

In this situation, I have to use dynamic query instead of native query. So I'd like to use dynamic query and face this problem.

Please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

there is no date_add in JPA so you would have few options:

- use native query https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries
- implement custom jpa function for date modifications
- parametrize query

personally i would go with query parametrization as it is easier to test and maintain in the long-run.